# Semeval twitter data download is not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, terminal, sentiment-analysis

I want to download the training set of the following dataset: http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/index.php?id=data-and-tools

I am required to use a script to download the tweets from their respective ids and the script is on this github: https://github.com/seirasto/twitter_download

When I run the following command in powershell:

```
python download_tweets_user_api.py --dist input.txt --output output.txt --user
```

I get

```
https://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When trying to run this command:

```
python download_tweets_api.py --dist=tweeti-a.dist.tsv
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: download_tweets_api.py [-h] [--partial PARTIAL] --dist DIST --output OUTPUT
download_tweets_api.py: error: argument --dist: can't open 'tweeti-a.dist.tsv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tweeti-a.dist.tsv'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: following
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/semevaltweet/4e45k1QkHk4
I copied the training data ids file (downloaded from the data & tools page http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/index.php?id=data-and-tools), more precisely I copied the file twitter-2016train-A.txt in the same directory of the scripts and I renamed it as tweeti-a.dist.tsv
After that, I unfortunately get an authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error can be avoided by removing or commenting the following line 7 of the download_tweets_user_api.py file:
`https://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/`

For the second error, use:

```
python download_tweets_api.py --dist={name-of-file} --output ouput.txt
```

instead of:

```
python download_tweets_api.py --dist=tweeti-a.dist.tsv
```

where {name-of-file} is the filename of the file that you downloaded from https://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/index.php?id=data-and-tools
Make sure the file is in the same directory where you run the command prompt and where download_tweets_api.py lies.

Assuming you have authorized twitter, change line 19:

```
MY_TWITTER_CREDS = os.path.expanduser('~/.my_app_credentials')
```

to:

```
MY_TWITTER_CREDS = os.path.expanduser('~/.twitter_oauth')
```

If you have not authorized twitter yet, open command prompt and import twitter package using `pip install twitter` and then run `twitter authorize`. Once you are redirected to a page, allow authorization and copy the pin back to command prompt.

Once this is done, your .twitter_oauth file will be created and you will be able to run the command that caused the error.